# Can I remove the format controls in the textareafor element?

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a project with a contact form. At the end I need a multi line text box, where people can simply put in whatever they feel like saying.

I currently am using the TextAreaFor element like this:

Model:

```
[DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
        public string Test { get; set; }
```

View:

```
<div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Test, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Test, new { @class = "form-control" })
                </div>
            </div>
```

But when I run it I get this:

[image]

This is all good, but is there a way I can remove the formatting options? They aren't really needed and take up a big portion of the available space.

Comment: Which library are you using for this Wysiwyg editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formatting tools could be caused by 3rd party library, more precise by its selector rules.

Since you use `tinymce` you could exclude/include particular textarea by editing its selectors, because by default `tinymce` add formatting tools to all textareas. Please check [this link](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3Aselector)

So you could use something like this for TinyMCE 4:

```
selector: "textarea", // default rule, which affect all textareas on your site
selector: "textarea.mytext", // affect only textareas with mytext class
selector : "textarea:not(.noformat)", // affect all textareas except the textarea with noformat class
```

If you want to use excluding option don't forget to use `noformat` class for textarea where you don't want formatting tools.

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Test, new { @class = "form-control noformat" })
```

Comment: TextArea for yields the same result, I do have TinyMCE in the project for a different page. But I thought it only used textarea for. Thanks, I'll see what I can do about this.

Comment: I gave this page another layout page, without the Tiny MCE javascript in the heading, but it still shows it like this.

Comment: @Robin I updated the answer, please try this solution.